# How to modify "this" in javascript

Tags: javascript

I find myself wanting to re-define "this" many times through the day. Could someone please tell me how to achieve this or why I cannot?

For example:

```
this = $('div')[0];
```

Why i would like to do this: working with 'this' is more natural then passing a reference through a function call. 'this' should refer to the calling object inside of a function for example:

```
var my_div = $('#some_div');
my_div.click(function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

What gets sent to the log is a reference to the window not to the div that is calling the function.

Every onchange event handler I write is forced to take 'this' as a parameter in order to maintain reference to the calling object. To me this seems broken.

Comment: Please provide more information, your question is really unclear

Comment: Why would you need to do this? The `this` keyword has specific meanings depending on how you call the function it's in. It's better to learn what they are.

Comment: Have a read of [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).  It will probably cover everything you ever wanted to know...

Comment: Instead you can use: `$this = this;`

Comment: Sounds like you really should be using bind, call, or apply.

Comment: *"What gets sent to the log is a reference to the window not to the div that is calling the function."* Not true. In your example, `this` will refer to the DOM element with ID `some_div`. I think the problem is rather that you don't understand how `this` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.call(context[, params])`and `.apply(context[, arguments])` to do this. For example:

```
function move(x, y) {
    this.style.left = x + "px";
    this.style.top = y + "px";
};

// now this in move refers to the div element
move.call($('div')[0], 100, 200);
```

But you can't just overwrite `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to do you can use javascript's `bind`. It modifies the context of the `this` keyword on function calls. You can take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind for more information but here's a simple example.

```
var obj1 = {
    x: 5,
    getX: function() {
        return this.x;
    }
};

var obj2 = {
    x: 7
}

var xVal = obj1.getX(); //this = obj1

var boundedFunc = obj1.getX.bind(obj2); //this = obj2
var boundedXVal = boundedFunc();

console.log(xVal); //prints 5
console.log(boundedXVal); //prints 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly speculation on my part as I do not know the exact answer to your question, but I believe it is because whenever you use "this" you are inside of an object. You cannot change an object that you are already inside of because this would produce some unwanted results. Individual things inside of "this" is fine thought

```
this.someVariable = "something else"
```

Comment: Technically you can with `.call` and `.apply`. It's how we commonly convert array-like-objects into true arrays for example

Comment: I didn't know that was possible, thanks for the clarification